# psycopg2: WHERE =ANY with multiple columns

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

PostgreSQL v14
Psycopg2 v2.9.3

I can do this in straight PostgreSQL / pgsql, however I can't seem to get it in Psycopg2.

Given an example table:

```
    CREATE TABLE accounts (
       id BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
       account_name TEXT,
       account_number TEXT NOT NULL,
       other_account_info TEXT
    )

    -- Enforces uniqueness for the pair, both non-null
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX accounts_name_number_unique_idx ON accounts (account_name, account_number);

    -- Enforces uniqueness for the account_number for a non-null account_name
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX accounts_number_unique_idx ON accounts (account_number) WHERE account_name IS NULL;
```

I want to match on an accounts record using 2 fields by doing something like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM accounts
WHERE (account_name, account_number) =ANY(VALUES('name', number'), ('name1', 'number2'))
```

This of course works just fine when I run it directly in psql, however I can't get psycopg2 to format the SQL properly.

**NOTE:** I don't want to simply do `WHERE account_name = %(account_name)s AND account_number = %(account_number)s` because I will have an unknown number of account_name / account_number pairs to query on and don't want to dynamically generate the SQL.

I've tried the following:

```
template: str = f"""
SELECT *
FROM accounts
WHERE (account_name, account_number) = ANY(VALUES%(account_list)s)
"""

inserts: dict = {'account_list': ('account_name1', 'account_number1')}
execute(cur=_cursor, sql=template, argslist=inserts)
```

And that works!  But, as soon as I add a second account_name and account_number to the parameters and make it a tuple of tuples it breaks with: `UndefinedFunction: operator does not exist: text = record`

```
template: str = f"""
SELECT *
FROM accounts
WHERE (account_name, account_number) = ANY(VALUES%(account_list)s)
"""

inserts: dict = { 'account_list': (('account_name1', 'account_number1',),('account_name2', 'account_number2',)) }
execute(cur=_cursor, sql=template, argslist=inserts)
```

I've also tried make the parameter a list and removing "VALUES" from the SQL template, but it breaks and I get `DatatypeMismatch: cannot compare dissimilar column types text and unknown at record column 1`

```
template: str = f"""
SELECT *
FROM accounts
WHERE (account_name, account_number) = ANY(%(account_list)s)
"""

inserts: dict = { 'account_list': [('account_name1', 'account_number1'),('account_name2', 'account_number2')] }
execute(cur=_cursor, sql=template, argslist=inserts)
```

I recognize that in some situations, I need to cast the individual parameters, but I can't figure out how to do that in psycopg2.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Read [List adaptation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-list)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks, and I did, but that doesn't explain adapting a list of tuples.  Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Have you actually tried `ANY(VALUES('name', number'), ('name1', 'number2'))` in a query? I believe you are going to get a `subquery has too many columns` error.

Comment: If I run a straight query, and with only 1 "(" after VALUES, then I get more than 1 row (not column) returned by subquery.  Psycopg2 puts a second "(", so ANY(VALUES(( which then prompts the "no operator matches the given name and argument types" error that I mentioned above.  In trying to keep the question a bit simpler, I didn't delve into my ultimate goal which is that there is a join table which links to the accounts table and the names table and I'm trying to find an account row which has a join table row that links to a specific name.  Basically, trying to resolve a name based on account

Comment: I figured once figuring the ANY part out, I would modify for EXISTS and be able to get the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `any()` it may be easier to use `unnest()` to create a temporary table of your account_name and account_number pairs of interest and join this to your accounts table.

```
sql = "select * from accounts
       join unnest(%(names)s, %(numbers)s) as query(name, number) 
       on query.name = accounts.account_name and 
          query.number = accounts.account_number;"
accounts = (('account_name1', 'account_number1',),
            ('account_name2', 'account_number2',))
names, numbers = map(list, zip(*accounts))
cur.execute(sql, {"names": names, "numbers": numbers})
```

I have not paid any attention to handling of null values of accout_name in this example as I was unclear how you were planning on handling equality in this situation and you may need to adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: Beautiful!  I implemented and handled NULL values for the account_name (NULLABLE) by using "query.name IS NOT DISTINCT FROM accounts.account_name".  Also, as this query is part of a larger COALESCE(...), it can only return 1 row, so I am using DISTINCT on the accounts id field (which is what I wanted to begin with and which is supported by the rest of the tables).  Thanks again!!